# How I get data in one column and put into a list using pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, pandas, dataframe

I have data such as:

```
no    height    weight
 1       150        70
 2       160        75
 3       170        80
```

I want to get data from one column to a list, for example, I took the height column so that list will be [150, 160, 170].

When I search on the internet, it says that I can use pandas:

```
df['Height']
```

But, the "no." column is still at left, and when I put it into a list, obviously it will fail. Please, help me.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest option is to call the `.tolist()` method of the object you obtained, or simply pass it as an argument to a `list`:

```py
>>> df['height']
no
0    150
1    160
2    170
Name: height, dtype: int64
>>> df['height'].tolist()
[150, 160, 170]
>>> list(df['height'])
[150, 160, 170]
```